# How to get key value of array?

Tags: php, arrays, key

How do I get the value of a key of any array item? Like how a foreach loop turns it into $k => $v...except I only want to do that once, so no need for a loop. Do I really need to make a new array that it flips to?

Take this for example.

```
1 => array(
               'street' => 'Street Address ',
               'town' => 'Town/City '
              ),
    2 => array(
               'state' => 'State '
              ),
```

Those are arrays inside a bigger array. And now I tried to do this

```
array_flip($thatarrayupthere[2]['state'])
```

What I want to receive from that is "state" because that is the key name. But I'm getting errors.

Comment: `$thatarrayupthere[2]['state']` is not an array, and you're not assigning the result of `array_flip()` to anything.

Comment: Well I don't really want to assign it, I just want to echo the key name. Do I really have to assign it?

Comment: `'state'` is the key name, you apparently already know it. `key($thatarrayupthere[2])`; will probably return it, but you can't guarantee that `$thatarrayupthere[2]` is always in a reset state.

Comment: Yeah but I want it to be dynamic....like for a better example, how would you echo the $array[1]['town'] key name?

Comment: With `foreach ($thatarrayupthere as $key => $value) { echo $key }`

Comment: But by using a foreach it has to go through the first value before 'town' right? I think I'm just complicating this, I just wanted to see if there was a shortcut to not having to make a new array in order to skip around. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I'm not exactly sure what you wan't, but if you just want to get the key of the second array in any given array this might help.

```
$key = key($array[2]);
```

In your example above you will get "state" in your $key variable.

Answer (score 0):

```
$key  = array_keys($array[2]);

print_r($key);
```

ref: http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-keys.php